# Как обратиться к стороннему скрипту?

Tags: post, php, get

Есть скрипт, который находится на другом сайте. Мне нужно передать ему параметры, получить результат (не обязательно, но желательно), ну и продолжить выполнение своего скрипта на своём сайте. Как это лучше всего сделать?

Пока что думаю решить так:

```
$url = fopen('http://ne-moi-sait.sru/script.php?login=admin&password=qwerty', "rb");
$text = stream_get_contents($url);
fclose($url);
print $text;
```

Или как можно передать данные GET, POST другому скрипту, и продолжить работу своего скрипта?

Comment: Спасибки. А какие минусы у "моего" способа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post средствами php - только через curl. Или, если ответ не важен, то можете поместить на страницу форму и указать ей action на нужный вам сайт. Но при этом пользователь перейдет на тот сайт.
Get делается просто: `$a = file_get_contents('http://url.com/script.php?key=value');` . Или тем же curl'ом.

Comment: Ну не только через курл. Сокеты еще никто не отменял)) Может человек решит углубиться в теорию и изучить как работает система целиком =)

Comment: Ага, уже углубилась... :-) Мой хостинг не поддерживает cURL.

Comment: http://www.web-junior.net/otpravka-post-zaprosov-s-pomoshhyu-php-chast-1/
Тогда вот неплохая статья)))

Answer (score 2):

[**CURL**](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=curl+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Answer (score 2):

[Сюда](http://www.web-junior.net/otpravka-post-zaprosov-s-pomoshhyu-php-chast-1/)